# java 17 generate xml from xsd file

Tags: java, xml, xsd, java-17

I migrate from java 8 to java 17
in java 8 I used this plugin to generate xml from xsd:

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>

                        <version>0.13.2</version> (I tried to update to 0.15.2)
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-source</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/META-INF/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                                    <schemaIncludes>
                                        <include>fe2_flux_generique.xsd</include>
                                    </schemaIncludes>
                                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/META-INF/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                                    <bindingIncludes>
                                        <include>fe2_flux_generique.xjb</include>
                                    </bindingIncludes>
                                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/generated</generateDirectory>
                                    <generatePackage>fr.icdc.dei.ddr.fe2.xml.domain</generatePackage>

                                    <!-- Other configuration options -->

                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

xsd file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="urn:ddr:fe2:flux:1.0"
    xmlns:flux="urn:ddr:fe2:flux:1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    version="1.0.0">
*********************
***************
*******
</xsd:schema>
```

xjb file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <jxb:serializable uid="1" />

        <!-- date time adapter -->
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar"
            xmlType="xsd:dateTime"
            parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />

    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

In java 17 the build terminate successufly but no files are generated, I tried to add the jkarta dependency, and change in xsd & xjb file the xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" to xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="3.0" but doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Once I used this plugin also.Excactly I don't know why, but I had problems with this plugin also and since then prefer the org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/schema</source>
                </sources>
                <xjbSources>
                    <xjbSource>src/main/xjb</xjbSource>
                </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

- Generally putting generated stuff to src isn't a good idea. Better leave the default (in this case target/generated-sources/jaxb).

  - You would have to explicitly exclude it from versioning,
  - mvn clean wouldn't remove it by default.
- Also you should be aware that files within src/main/resources would be automatically added to your JAR file. May be you intend to use the schema files for runtime validation of incoming XML. Then this would be ok. The bindings files are for code generation only. You will never need them within your JAR file.
- Instead of telling xjc to which package you want to generate your classes by a property in the POM you should better use the bindings customization. This has the advantage that everything affecting your code is in one place. Furthermore for multiple schemas you would have to add more executions to your POM vs. adding another bindings definition to your bindings file.

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schema/fe2_flux_generique.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="fr.icdc.dei.ddr.fe2.xml.domain"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```